# Large XML with selective parsing

Tags: dom, xpath, xml-parsing, saxparser

We are building kind of staging application where we receive large XML files (ISO 20022 messages) with tons of elements defined in it. We just store these XML's in database as XMLtype and send them to downstream system for further processing.

There is GUI where we need to display some of those XML elements to Users and allow to update some of fields and store it again in database as new XML message

Trying to find best efficient implementation stack with respect to performance and memory.

One idea is to identify XML elements which are required to be displayed in UI and have such elements defined as meta fields with XPath. Trying to avoid parsing entire XML.

Appreciate any ideas to process large XML when only certain elements are required to be viewed and updated.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that using XML Data Types in common RDBMS is OK, but not great. I found that native XML DBMS work much better for ISO 20022, such as [Marklogic](http://www.marklogic.com/) or [eXistdb](http://exist-db.org/).

If you want to continue with an RDBMS' XML Type, then use XQuery to pull the items you want. Oracle call this [XMLQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb_xquery.htm). Microsoft have a [query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx) function for XQuery.

As XQuery is based on XPath, then yes, using XPath is a good way to achieve what you want.